# How and when to use Ember.Application register and inject methods?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to understand how to use Ember.Application [register](http://www.ember-doc.com/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_register) & [inject](http://www.ember-doc.com/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_inject) methods

**What use case are these functions designed for?
How are they to be used and when?**

I'd really like to know!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Ember by default does dependency injection when it boots your application using mostly conventions, for example if you use ember-data then an instance of the `store` class is injected in every `route` and `controller` in your application, so you can later get a reference by simply doing `this.get('store')` inside any route or controller.

For example here is a code extract where the default `store` get's registered (taken from the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta/packages/ember-data/lib/initializers.js#L39))

```
Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', function(Application) {
  Application.initializer({
    name: "store",

    initialize: function(container, application) {
      application.register('store:main', application.Store);
      ...
    }

    container.lookup('store:main');
  }
});
```

And then injected ([source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta/packages/ember-data/lib/initializers.js#L75))

```
Application.initializer({
  name: "injectStore",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    application.inject('controller', 'store', 'store:main');
    application.inject('route', 'store', 'store:main');
    application.inject('dataAdapter', 'store', 'store:main');
  }
  ...
});
```

In other words `register` and `inject` are methods to register dependencies and inject them yourself.

Let's assume you have a `Session` object which you populate after a server request on application start, and which you want to have a reference to in every controller, you could do something like this:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function(){
    this.register('session:current', App.Session, {singleton: true});
    this.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:current');
  }
});

App.Session = Ember.Object.extend({
  sessionHash: ''
});
```

This code would set the `session` property of every controller instance to a singleton instance of `App.Session`, so you could in any controller do `this.get('session')` and get a reference to it, and since it's defined as a singleton it would be always the same `session` object.

With `register` you can register controllers, models, views, or any arbitrary object type. `inject`, in the other hand, can inject onto all *instances* of a given class. For example `inject('model', 'session', 'session:current')` would also inject the `session` property with the `session:current` instance into all models. To inject the `session` object, let's say onto the `IndexView` you could do `inject('view:index', 'session', 'session:current')`.

Although `register` and `inject` are very powerful you should use them wisely and only in the case you really know there is no other way to achieve your goal, I guess the lack of documentation is an indicator for discouragement.

### Update - No good explanation without a working example

Since It's mostly a must to provide a working example with an explanation, there it goes: http://jsbin.com/usaluc/6/edit. Notice how in the example we can simply access the mentioned `sessionHash` by referring to the current controller's session object with `{{controller.session.sessionHash}}` in every route we are in, this is the merit of what we have done by registering and injecting the `App.Session` object in every controller in the application.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm building an interactive cheatsheet for Ember.js, do you mind if I put this on there? You can see it here: http://embersherpa.com/ It would probably go under Em.Application.register & Em.Application.inject. What do you think?

Comment: @tarasm, nice idea the cheatsheet - go ahead! And if you come across `Ember.Component` you can also use this answer if you want which I just finished to write: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482457/architecture-for-reusable-object-in-ember/

Comment: sweet, I'll do that. Thank you! I want to follow you, what's your Twitter?

Comment: @tarasm, my twitter is the same nick as here on SO *intuitivepixel* However I'm not very active there, but what not is can still change :)

Comment: I followed you. It's never too late to start :)

Comment: For the life of me, I can't get Ember to inject anything into a view. `App.inject('veiw:index', 'mything', 'foo:mything');`, but then afterwards, I try to `this.get("mything")` in an event handler in my `App.IndexView`, and `undefined`. Something very counter-intuitive is going on here.

Comment: What does :main or :current mean in your example? ('store:main' and 'session:current').

Comment: @Martin `:main`, `:current` etc. are simply like labels. They are useful if you have more then one of the same object with a somewhat different implementation that you want to register, `myObject:basic, MyObjectBasic ...` or `myObject:advanced, MyObjectAdvanced ...`. I hope it makes makes sense?

Comment: @EmberSherpa http://embersherpa.com/cheatsheet/App.inject/ returns an Apache 404 Error page.

Comment: @intuitivepixel you said to use this wisely, and I agree. Would you say it's a good use to take json that is bootstrapped in the HTML document to populate models? I ended up setting up a service as an empty object, and an initializer that populates that service with .reopen, and then populates some models with appropriate data, and then injects some other data into a controller. This seems to work well for me, but I'm not sure if it's "wise" or if there's another option.

Comment: How can you inject something into the application instance outside of an initializer?

Comment: @intuitivepixel Hi, I just asked a question that directly relates to this one. I'm trying to find where to put the call to the server you mentioned. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306080/where-in-ember-to-make-initial-session-status-xhr-to-server

Answer (score 8):

A common use case is to provide the current loggedin user property to controllers and routes as in https://github.com/kelonye/ember-user/blob/master/lib/index.js and https://github.com/kelonye/ember-user/blob/master/test/index.js

Comment: Hi Michael, I finally got a chance to look over everything again. Thank you for your example, I starred your library.