# Architecture for reusable object in ember

Tags: ember.js

I am building an admin dashboard using ember. I want to create a reusable chart object of which I can have multiple instances throughout the application. The chart object should have a template consisting of some markup and a canvas element of which I need the id after insertion in the DOM in order to attach the actual chart (chart.js). I have tried several approaches, but I can not seem to figure out the right architecture to do this.

What would be the right architecture in ember to achieve the above?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this http://adminjs.com/?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### [`Ember.Component`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html) is your friend

As @raulbrito already mentioned, the best way to go if you want reusable components in ember is indeed to use the new `Ember.Component` which is heavily based on the [new w3 draft for web components](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/) and thus beeing future proof.

I've tried to make a simple example on how this could be implemented.
Given a simple `route` where the `model` hook returns some static data:

#### Index Route

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.Object.create({
      modelOne: data,
      modelTwo: data2
    });
  }
});
```

`data` and `data2` are simply static objects globally defined for simplicity *(as you will see [in the demo](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/146/edit))*, but this could be also data coming from a backend or from fixtures etc.

#### Index template

In the template then we insert our chart component with the line `{{line-chart data=model.modelOne}}` and as you can see, we also set the `data` attribute to the index model `model.modelOne` or `model.modelTwo`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <h2>Chart one</h2>
  {{line-chart data=model.modelOne}}

  <h2>Chart two</h2>
  {{line-chart data=model.modelTwo}}
</script>
```

#### Component Template

Our component template looks fairly simple because it will render a simple `canvas` element, but it could be as complex as needed, on how to use `Ember.Component` please refer also to the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/line-chart">
</script>
```

#### Component Subclass

```
App.LineChartComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'canvas',
  attributeBindings: ['width', 'height'],
  width: '480',
  height: '360',
  data: null,
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var ctx = this.get('element').getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(this.get('data'));
  }
});
```

Note the naming is important here, Ember knows which subclass powers a component based on its name. For example, if you have a component called `line-chart`, you would create a subclass called `App.LineChartComponent`. If your component was called `bar-chart-simple`, the class name would be `App.BarChartSimpleComponent` and so on. Ember will look for a class with the camelized name of the component, followed by `Component`.

So, and since `Ember.Component` extends from `Ember.View` we can define all sorts of properties `Ember.View` supports like `tagName`. In our case we use `canvas` because this is what `chart.js` needs to work. As you can see we have also defined some `attributeBindings` to control the `width` and `height` of the `canvas` from inside ember. The component has also a `data` attribute *(which could be called whatever you find appropriate)* defined on which we later set our model data in the template returned from the `IndexRoute` `model` hook. And finally in your `didInsertElement` hook of our component we initialize the chart passing with `this.get('data')` the data object to new created `Chart.js` class.

```
var ctx = this.get('element').getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(this.get('data'));
```

And last but not least, please see here for a [working example](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/146/edit) of the above explained.

Hope it helps.

### Update in response to your last comment

I've tried to simulate a delay in the resolution of the `model` hook to mimic a response from a backend, as you can see the template rendering is waiting for the `model` promise to resolve first. Basically what I've done is to use `Ember.run.later` with a delay of 2000ms that resolves the promise once timed out:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
      Ember.run.later(function() {
        var m = Ember.Object.create({
          modelOne: data,
          modelTwo: data2
        });
        resolve(m);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
});
```

And just for fun I've also added a `LoadingRoute` to show a spinner while the promise resolution is waiting for data, the `LoadingRoute` is a less documented feature of ember, you can read more about it here: https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589 under *How do I put up a (global) Loading Spinner during a transition w/ Promises?*

Plase see here for a updated example: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/145/edit

### Update in response to @SamSelikoff's comment

As for the above mentioned `LoadingRoute` @SamSelikoff pointed out that it's officially documented now: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_initial-routes

Comment: Wow this is great! I got the static example working. However, what if the data is loaded with ajax? The component is instantiated before the data returns from the backend, thus the `model.modelOne` will be null when passed in the handlebars helper. Also what if the data changes (when new data is fetched from the backend). Is it possible to bind and observe the component's data attribute to the model?

Comment: @ThomasK, you can do all sorts of things to update your chart data, I've updated my answer with a simulated delay when fetching the data, have a look.

Comment: Wow nice. I took a slightly different approach. I set another property `modelOneData` from the ajax callback and bind and observe that property to/in my component.

Comment: For reference I recently got the LoadingRoute into the docs: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_initial-routes

Comment: @SamSelikoff, oh thanks for pointing that out, I'll update my answer, so much changes lately on the ember docs (for good) - really hard to keep up without making it a full time job :)

Comment: I posted a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527991/ember-use-controller-data-in-route-or-how-to-fetch-data-properly

Answer (score 3):

I have some thoughts on this, so just throwing it out there, in case it helps you.

First of all, I would advise you to go and watch Sam Selikoff's presentation on using Ember with D3. All the info here: http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/2013/08/09/ember-d3-simple-dashboards/ . Also, don't miss the comments section on the blog post.

It is a great example on using Ember Views to wrap D3 objects, and can be a good *reusable* solution. The caveat here is that Ember Views require a backing controller that provides the data. Depending on where in the application you would want to reuse your charts, this might be inconvenience.

The alternative would be to use Ember Components. In that case, you just need to define the Component and associated handlebars template. The good thing about it is that it won't need any backing controller, therefore freeing you from a dependency, which might make it easier for you to add such a component in different places of your application. Without a concrete example, I think it's hard to reach a great conclusion, but maybe this will help you clarify things.