# Ember: use controller data in route or how to fetch data properly

Tags: ember.js

This question is a follow up on my previous question: [Architecture for reusable object in ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482457/architecture-for-reusable-object-in-ember)

In my app I create multiple charts using an `Ember.Component`. The daterange for all the charts is controlled by a `Daterangepicker` which has its own controller etc.. Now the data for each chart is fetched in the IndexRoute (with an ajax call), and the daterange is passed in the query string.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to access the daterange from the IndexRoute. Here's my code:

**IndexRoute.js**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(){

    var that = this;

    return Ember.Object.extend({
      registrationsData: null,
      registrations: function() {

        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate('ysu_user_api_statistics_registrations', {startDate: that.dateRange.startDate, endDate: that.dateRange.endDate}),
            success: function(data) {

                var labels = [];
                        var values = [];

                        var chartData = {
                            labels : data.labels,
                            datasets : [
                            {
                                data : data.values,
                            }
                            ],
                        };

                        self.set('registrationsData', chartData);

                    }
                });
        }.property(),
    }).create();

  },
    dateRange: Ember.Object.create({
        id: 1,
        startDate: '2013-08-01',
        endDate: '2013-08-31'
  }),
 });
```

**Index.hbs**

```
{{ my-chart title="Registrations" dataBinding=model.registrations registrationsDataBinding=model.registrationsData}}
```

**MyChartComponent.js**

```
App.MyChartComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
  dataBinding: null,
  registrationsDataBinding: null,
  dateRangeBinding: null,
  modelDateRangeBinding: null,
  chartContext: null,
  myChartController: null,
  didInsertElement: function() {

    /* Create and set controller */
    if (!this.get('myChartController')) {
      myChartController = new App.MyChartController()
      this.set('myChartController', myChartController);
    }

    this.set('chartContext', $(this.get('element')).find('canvas')[0].getContext("2d"));

  },

  drawChart: function() {

    if(this.get('chartContext')) {

        var ctx = this.get('chartContext');

        var options = {
            bezierCurve : false,
            pointDotRadius : 6,
            pointDotStrokeWidth : 4,
            datasetStrokeWidth : 4,
        }

      var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(this.get('registrationsDataBinding'), options);

    }

  }.observes('registrationsDataBinding', 'myChartController.dateRange'),

});
```

**MyChartController.js**

```
App.MyChartController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    container: App.__container__,
    needs: ['daterangepicker'],
    dateRange: 'controllers.daterangepicker.selectedRange',
    dateRangeBinding: 'controllers.daterangepicker.selectedRange',
});
```

I must admit, this setup feels kinda weird. So ultimately my question is:
What would be the correct way to fetch data for my charts based on startDate and endDate set in my DatePickerController?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this problem as well.

In some of my apps, I've needed the URL to control the date range (e.g. a particular month). In these cases, I would created a `MonthRoute` and a `MonthModel` - think of it as a monthly report. The `MonthModel` has a `hasMany` property of the actual data I wanted to chart:

```
App.Month = DS.Model.extend({
  companies: DS.hasMany('App.Company')
});
```

A datepicker would let the user enter a new route, which would fetch (say) the `Jan-2013` month model

```
{
  month: {
    id: 'Jan-2013',
    companies: [
      {name: 'Acme, Inc', revenue: 10425, ...},
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, I would set the embedded companies data on my `CompaniesController` in the `setupController` hook:

```
App.MonthRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    this.controllerFor('companies').set('model', model.get('companies'));
  }
});
```

Then, I would do the various array manipulations on my `CompaniesController`, and make that data available to my charts.

I have some [code for this up on github](https://github.com/samselikoff/talks/blob/master/d3-ember-simple-dashboard/part5-flexibility.html), as well as a [demo](http://samselikoff.github.io/talks/d3-ember-simple-dashboard/part5-flexibility.html). I'd be interested to hear your thoughts.