# Ember.js: How to use Em.computed.alias for an imported object?

Tags: import, ember.js, controller, alias

I am importing an object, `Delivery` into my Outbox controller and would like to make a computed alias for it within my controller, something like:

```
emailStateOptions: Em.computed.alias('Delivery.ORDERED_STATES')
```

but that's not working, so instead, I am doing this which works but is verbose:

```
import Delivery from 'app/models/delivery';

var Outbox = Ember.ArrayController.extend({  
  emailStateOptions: function() {
    return Delivery.ORDERED_STATES;
  }.property(),
)}
```

Is there a way to use computed.alias here?

Answer (score 0):

For Em.computed.alias to work, `Delivery` would have to be defined as a property in your controller.

Although I don't know the overall architecture of your app, a better way to get the `ORDERED_STATES` into the controller might be to use Ember's **injector** pattern.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18210271/2319023 a good explanation on this.