# Ember.js Application.inject circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dependency-injection, frontend, single-page-application

Hi, I'm about 2 weeks into building my application with ember.js, and the time has come to pull together my project layout into its final shape. To that end, I started looking into using Ember's register / inject mechanism instead of just creating global singletons and attaching them to my App object (for an excellent description of dependency injection in Ember, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18210271/2405595))

I'm stuck with standard dependency injection dilemma - circular references.

Let's say, I have two manager-like classes that I need available throughout application. Let's call them AuthManager and DataManager.

```js
App.AuthManager = Ember.Object.extend({
    logIn: function (user) {
        var promise = this.dataManager.post("/session/new", user);
        //...
    }
});

App.DataManager = Ember.Object.extend({
    getJSON: function (url) {
        if (!this.authManager.get("isLoggedIn")) {
            return false;
        }
        //...
    }
});
```

So, as you see dataManager needs access to authManager and vice-versa.
My naive take at a solution was something like this:

```js
App.initializer({
    name: "dataManager",

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register("my:dataManager", application.DataManager);
        application.inject("my:authManager", "dataManager", "my:dataManager");
    }
});

App.initializer({
    name: "authManager",

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register("my:authManager", application.AuthManager);
        application.inject("my:dataManager", "authManager", "my:authManager");
    }
});
```

Predictably, this results in a dead loop. I was hoping dependency injection system would try some crafty juggle, like node's `require` does, but no.

I have tried:

- Moving the first inject into the second initializer, after `my:authManager` is registered.
- Moving the first inject into its own initializer, after the first two
- Putting any combination of these into the `Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', ...)` from the linked article

Unfortunately, everything I tried ended in stack overflow (pun intended :-)).

Am I missing something? The documentation is pretty sparse in this area.
Of course, I can always manually lookup instance after the 'official' injection, but I was hoping for some more elegant solution.

Comment: Where are you grabbing instances of authManager/dataManager?  Are you also injecting them on the controller/route?

Comment: Yes, I use them in other places as well, including routes and controllers. I see where you're going, I can grab them off ApplicationRoute, for example, instead of using injected instances. However, I'm not sure how that's better architecture-wise than just creating globals and sticking them to App object.

Comment: actually I wasn't going there, but if you're fine namespacing them I'll give you a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely have a circular dependency, and if you were using a different language I'd tell you to use the inversion of control pattern, but it's a little difficult using your problem and the container.

### Solution 1

If you're fine adding them under a namespace such as `manager` or something like that then here's a solution (it's tightly coupled, but the code is tightly coupled already, almost enough that they could be together or a mixin on the other).

```
App.Manager = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function(){
    // late fake injection
    this.authManager.dataManager = this.dataManager;
    this.dataManager.authManager = this.authManager;
  }
});


App.initializer({
    name: "manager",
    after:['dataManager', 'authManager'],

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register("my:manager", application.Manager);
        application.inject("my:manager", "dataManager", "my:dataManager");
        application.inject("my:manager", "authManager", "my:authManager");
        application.inject("controller", "manager", "my:manager");
        application.inject("route", "manager", "my:manager");
    }
});

App.initializer({
    name: "dataManager",

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register("my:dataManager", application.DataManager);
    }
});

App.initializer({
    name: "authManager",

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register("my:authManager", application.AuthManager);
    }
});
```

And an example:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mopaquko/2/edit

### Solution 2

On another note, this creates a new instance on each route/controller.  If you only need one instance.  You can do it like so, much easier and doesn't need the namespace.

```
App.initializer({
    name: "joinManagers",
    after:['dataManager', 'authManager'],

    initialize: function (container, application) {
      var dataManager = container.lookup('my:dataManager'),
          authManager = container.lookup('my:authManager');
        
        authManager.dataManager = dataManager;
        dataManager.authManager = authManager;
      
        application.register("my:jointDataManager", dataManager, {instantiate:false});
        application.register("my:jointAuthManager", authManager, {instantiate:false});
        application.inject("controller", "dataManager", "my:jointDataManager");
        application.inject("controller", "authManager", "my:jointAuthManager");
        application.inject("route", "dataManager", "my:jointDataManager");
        application.inject("route", "authManager", "my:jointAuthManager");
    }
});


App.initializer({
    name: "dataManager",

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register("my:dataManager", application.DataManager);
    }
});

App.initializer({
    name: "authManager",

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register("my:authManager", application.AuthManager);
    }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mopaquko/3/edit

### Solution 3

As was pointed out, Ember's container create's singletons by default, you can eagerly create the copies then allow ember to still resolve based on the original namespace.

```
App.initializer({
    name: "joinManagers",
    after:['dataManager', 'authManager'],

    initialize: function (container, application) {
      var dataManager = container.lookup('my:dataManager'),
          authManager = container.lookup('my:authManager');

        authManager.dataManager = dataManager;
        dataManager.authManager = authManager;

        application.inject("controller", "dataManager", "my:dataManager");
        application.inject("controller", "authManager", "my:authManager");
        application.inject("route", "dataManager", "my:dataManager");
        application.inject("route", "authManager", "my:authManager");
    }
});


App.initializer({
    name: "dataManager",

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register("my:dataManager", application.DataManager);
    }
});

App.initializer({
    name: "authManager",

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register("my:authManager", application.AuthManager);
    }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mopaquko/7/edit

Comment: That's it! The key was in the `after:` option and creating a new initializer to perform the manual injection. You don't, however, need to manually create and register new instances. `register()` creates singletons by default. I simplified [your js-bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mopaquko/6/edit?js,console) with what I feel is the final solution. If you think it's OK, please update your answer for visibility.

Comment: great point, I'm just doing it more verbosely than necessary in the second solution, I'll throw the third in as another viable option.  The only nuance with your approach is you've allowed it to inject them into the controller/route before they are fully functioning (granted this would probably never happen)

Comment: It shouldn't, because the third initializer is also a part of the dependency injection. Theoretically, all the DI should complete before the routing begins. Anyway, I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, unless something else in DI uses it (which obviously won't happen in this case)