# Emberjs service like feature(like angular)?

Tags: angularjs, ember.js

Lets say I have a function that talks to my server each 10 seconds and will do stuff (like update my models) if the server tell it so.

In angular I can create a service that will periodically do stuff while still be able to access my `$scope`(or `$rootScope`) how will I do such a thing in ember? how can i create a function that will run in the background and will be integrated with my ember app?

I've tried to search in the ember docs something similar to angular's service but i had no luck in this route so far :(

thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are a couple of places you could accomplish this, application route/container, I'll try and write up a response when I get to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Build up a controller in the application route, which essentially then just becomes a global controller you can access from all of your routes/controllers.

### Build during the application route startup phase

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(){
    // eagerly create the service controller instance, aka start the service
    var service = this.controllerFor('service');
  }
});

App.ServiceController = Em.Controller.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();

    this.startFooConsole();
  },
  startFooConsole: function(){
    Em.run.later(this, this.startFooConsole, 1000);
    console.log('hello world');
  },
  helloWorld: function(){
    console.log('hello world function');
  }
});
```

#### Access from a route

```
this.controllerFor('service').helloWorld();
```

#### Access from a controller

```
App.FooController = Em.Controller.extend({
  needs:['service'],
  someMethod: function(){
    this.get('controllers.service').helloWorld();
  }
})
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bukuvuho/1/edit

### Build using the container (Ember's Dependency Injection)

Using the container you can eagerly create an instance and attach it to all of the controllers, but then it shouldn't be a controller anymore (else it creates a circular reference).

```
App.Service = Em.Object.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();

    this.startFooConsole();
  },
  startFooConsole: function(){
    Em.run.later(this, this.startFooConsole, 1000);
    console.log('hello world');
  },
  helloWorld: function(){
    console.log('hello world function');
  }
});

App.initializer({
    name: "service",
    initialize: function (container, application) {
      // eagerly create the service and add it to the controllers/routes
      var service = application.Service.create();

        application.register("my:service", service, {instantiate:false});
        application.inject("controller", "service", "my:service");
        application.inject("route", "service", "my:service");
      // you also could put it in the app namespace
      application.service = service;
    }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bukuvuho/2/edit

Comment: wow thanks didnt know about run.later()  
 I didnt fully understand your latest code snippet App.initializer is it related to ember or just plain javascript?

Comment: The initializer is Ember's container, it's used for dependency injection.  Here's some more examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736022/ember-js-application-inject-circular-dependencies/22739463#22739463