# How do you manage state in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, state

How does one manage state in Emberjs?

If for example, you want to have a given "state" that works across several routes?

It seems like StateManager is no longer part of the core?

Comment: This gives an example of a shared object which can be used amongst all of your routes/controllers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913843/emberjs-service-like-featurelike-angular/23916151#23916151

Comment: Oh so like, in a controller?

Comment: It's an easy place to share state, or just an object injected into all of the controllers/routes.