# Where in Ember to make initial session status XHR to server

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When my ember application starts, I need to make a call to the server to check on the current session/user status. This needs to happen before any model hooks are run or any templates are rendered.

Where should this happen? I can't find quite the right place -- it keeps running a bit too late, or not at all. Right now I have it in my application route init with this._super.apply(), which works ok but it runs after child route model hooks.

I would think it should be an initializer, but the ember-cli docs specifically state that initializers should not contain XHR's (it states this under the generators section).

I'm essentially asking where to make the server request mentioned in the answer to this question: [How and when to use Ember.Application register and inject methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209862/how-and-when-to-use-ember-application-register-and-inject-methods)

Comment: how about in the `ApplicationRoute.beforeModel` ?

Comment: That was one of the first places I tried. The problem is that it doesn't run if you visit any route other than the application route. My understanding is that this is because the application route is not instantiated in those cases.

Comment: How about making a base route or mixin and make other route classes extend from that. You can make all ur model hooks call the base classes model hook with this._super()

Comment: Application route is always run, it is the base of the application.  It's only run once per page refresh, are you wanting to run multiple times per page refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your `application` route's `beforeModel` hook. Make sure that the call to check the session/user state returns a `RSVP.promise` and return this promise in the `beforeModel` hook. Ember provides the guarantee that execuction will block until this promise resolves/rejects. So redirect on failure/lack of session to your `auth` route or whatever makes sense or let execution continue as is. The `application` route  is the base route of the application and is entered every single time you refresh the app, including the initial load of the app. Each time subroutes change, the `application` route is not reentered and this hook will not be called. But if you are in a subroute and hit refresh, the `application` route will be entered and all hooks executed. Depending on your needs, you might also need to execute code in the subroute's `beforeModel` hooks as well. If so, use a `mixin` or make all subroutes extend from a common base `route` that handles this functionality

Comment: I had tried this but I thought beforeModel was not running. After your confident answer I tried it again and it worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After you create the ember app, you can call the deferReadiness() method and after this make your xhr call, on success then you call advanceReadiness()

This way the application wont continue to start until you xhr call is completed.

You can check more at the docs - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_deferReadiness